# BASH: Copy all files and directories into another directory in the same parent directory

Tags: bash, copy, glob, cp

I'm trying to make a simple script that copies all of my `$HOME` into another folder in `$HOME` called `Backup/`. This includes all hidden files and folders, and excludes `Backup/` itself. What I have right now for the copying part is the following:

```
shopt -s dotglob

for file in $HOME/*
do
    cp -r $file $HOME/Backup/
done
```

Bash tells me that it cannot copy `Backup/` into itself. However, when I check the contents of `$HOME/Backup/` I see that `$HOME/Backup/Backup/` exists.

The copy of `Backup/` in itself is useless. How can I get bash to copy over all the folders except `Backup/`. I tried using `extglob` and using `cp -r $HOME/!(Backup)/` but it didn't copy over the hidden files that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using `rsync` would be a better solution, but there is an easy way to skip a directory in `bash`:

```
for file in "$HOME/"*
do
    [[ $file = $HOME/Backup ]] && continue
    cp -r "$file" "$HOME/Backup/"
done
```

Comment: I looked up the syntax for the test && continue line you gave me and it seemed like it should work, but bash still gave me the `cp: cannot copy a directory into itself`

Comment: Try printing the value of `$file` prior to each `cp` command, to see exactly which argument to `cp` is causing the problem.

Comment: Printing `$file` shows me that it's not skipping `$HOME/Backup`. I've tried changing from double brackets to single brackets and making it a whole if statement 
`if [ "$file" != "$backupdir" ]; then 
echo "$file"
cp -r "$file" $backupdir
fi`
It acts like it's not even evaluating the `if`.

Comment: What is the exact value of `$backupdir`? Since this is a string comparison, both `$file` and `$backupdir` will need to be identical: same directory path, same trailing `/` (or lack of trailing `/`), etc. Two different strings that logically represent the same path will still compare as different.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond. That was the problem. I had $backupdir with a trailing `/`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

try rsync. you can exclude file/directories .

this is a good reference

```
http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_using_rsync_locally
```

Comment: I would prefer to do it entirely within bash, but I'll check out your link.

Answer (score 2):

Hugo,

A script like this is good, but you could try this:

cp -r * Backup/;
cp -r .* Backup/;

Another tool used with backups is tar. This compresses your backup to save disk space.

Also note, the * does not cover . hidden files.

Comment: I'm compressing the archive after everything is copied over into the backup directory. I have `shopt -s dotglob` so that the * covers hidden dot files. I just need a way to exclude that one directory from the whole thing because it's useless to have a copy of the directory used for the backup in the backup itself.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly (the other answers already did that), but try `cp -ua` when you want to use cp to make a backup. This recurses directories, copies rather than follows links, preserves permissions and only copies a file if it is newer than the copy at the destination.